# Reshape pandas dataframe from rows to columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reshape, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to reshape my data. At first glance, it sounds like a transpose, but it's not. I tried melts, stack/unstack, joins, etc.

**Use Case**

I want to have only one row per unique individual, and put all job history on the columns. For clients, it can be easier to read information across rows rather than reading through columns.

Here's the data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data1 = {'Name': ["Joe", "Joe", "Joe","Jane","Jane"],
        'Job': ["Analyst","Manager","Director","Analyst","Manager"],
        'Job Eff Date': ["1/1/2015","1/1/2016","7/1/2016","1/1/2015","1/1/2016"]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['Name', 'Job', 'Job Eff Date'])

df2
```

Here's what I want it to look like:
[Desired Output Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmCpb.png)

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`.T` within `groupby`

```
def tgrp(df):
    df = df.drop('Name', axis=1)
    return df.reset_index(drop=True).T

df2.groupby('Name').apply(tgrp).unstack()
```

[image]

---

#### Explanation

`groupby` returns an object that contains information on how the original series or dataframe has been grouped.  Instead of performing a `groupby` with a subsquent action of some sort, we could first assign the `df2.groupby('Name')` to a variable (I often do), say `gb`.

```
gb = df2.groupby('Name')
```

On this object `gb` we could call `.mean()` to get an average of each group.  Or `.last()` to get the last element (row) of each group.  Or `.transform(lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / x.std())` to get a zscore transformation within each group.  When there is something you want to do within a group that doesn't have a predefined function, there is still `.apply()`.

`.apply()` for a `groupby` object is different than it is for a `dataframe`.  For a dataframe, `.apply()` takes callable object as its argument and applies that callable to each column (or row) in the object. the object that is passed to that callable is a `pd.Series`.  When you are using `.apply` in a `dataframe` context, it is helpful to keep this fact in mind.  In the context of a `groupby` object, the object passed to the callable argument is a dataframe.  In fact, that dataframe is one of the groups specified by the `groupby`.

When I write such functions to pass to `groupby.apply`, I typically define the parameter as `df` to reflect that it is a dataframe.

Ok, so we have:

```
df2.groupby('Name').apply(tgrp)
```

This generates a sub-dataframe for each `'Name'` and passes that sub-dataframe to the function `tgrp`.  Then the `groupby` object recombines all such groups having gone through the `tgrp` function back together again.

It'll look like this.

[image]

I took the OP's original attempt to simply transpose to heart.  But I had to do some things first.  Had I simply done:

```
df2[df2.Name == 'Jane'].T
```

[image]

```
df2[df2.Name == 'Joe'].T
```

[image]

Combining these manually (without `groupby`):

```
pd.concat([df2[df2.Name == 'Jane'].T, df2[df2.Name == 'Joe'].T])
```

[image]

Whoa!  Now that's ugly.  Obviously the index values of `[0, 1, 2]` don't mesh with `[3, 4]`.  So let's reset.

```
pd.concat([df2[df2.Name == 'Jane'].reset_index(drop=True).T,
           df2[df2.Name == 'Joe'].reset_index(drop=True).T])
```

[image]

That's much better.  But now we are getting into the territory `groupby` was intended to handle.  So let it handle it.

Back to

```
df2.groupby('Name').apply(tgrp)
```

The only thing missing here is that we want to unstack the results to get the desired output.

[image]

Comment: How do I inspect something like this to dig deeper and figure out something like this ...groupby object are still hit or miss for me.

Comment: I pulled apart above.. Have a question for you,  It is  listed as an answers-- its not an answer.

Comment: I don't understand how df gets passed back in? It doesn't actually exist as a dataframe (in relation to the original data set).

Comment: @Christopher I updated the post with a bit of explanation

Comment: Thanks for the detailed write up. I'm still not clear on how tgrp works?

Comment: take `df2[df2.Name == 'Jane']` and run `tgrp` on it.  Like so:  `tgrp(df2[df2.Name == 'Jane'])`.  Observe the `df2[df2.Name == 'Jane']` before and after `tgrp` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Say you start by unstacking:

```
df2 = df2.set_index(['Name', 'Job']).unstack()
>>> df2
    Job Eff Date
Job Analyst Director    Manager
Name            
Jane    1/1/2015    None    1/1/2016
Joe 1/1/2015    7/1/2016    1/1/2016
In [29]:

df2
```

Now, to make things easier, flatten the multi-index:

```
df2.columns = df2.columns.get_level_values(1)
>>> df2
Job Analyst Director    Manager
Name            
Jane    1/1/2015    None    1/1/2016
Joe 1/1/2015    7/1/2016    1/1/2016
```

Now, just manipulate the columns:

```
cols = []
for i, c in enumerate(df2.columns):
    col = 'Job %d' % i
    df2[col] = c
    cols.append(col)
    col = 'Eff Date %d' % i
    df2[col] = df2[c]
    cols.append(col)
>>> df2[cols]
Job Job 0   Eff Date 0  Job 1   Eff Date 1  Job 2   Eff Date 2
Name                        
Jane    Analyst 1/1/2015    Director    None    Manager 1/1/2016
Joe Analyst 1/1/2015    Director    7/1/2016    Manager 1/1/2016
```

**Edit**

Jane was never a director (alas). The above code states that Jane became Director at `None` date. To change the result so that it specifies that Jane became `None` at `None` date (which is a matter of taste), replace

```
df2[col] = c
```

by

```
df2[col] = [None if d is None else c for d in df2[c]]
```

This gives

```
Job Job 0   Eff Date 0  Job 1   Eff Date 1  Job 2   Eff Date 2
Name                        
Jane    Analyst 1/1/2015    None    None    Manager 1/1/2016
Joe Analyst 1/1/2015    Director    7/1/2016    Manager 1/1/2016
```

​

Comment: Thanks Ami.

I think the code is giving Jane an extra job?

Comment: @Christopher Well, she can't complain, then, can she? :-) I'll look into it.

Comment: @Christopher I think it's more a matter of taste, but see update.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible workaround. Here, I first create a dictionary of the proper form and create a DataFrame based on the new dictionary:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)

dic = {}

for name, jobs in df.groupby('Name').groups.iteritems():
    if not dic:
        dic['Name'] = []
    dic['Name'].append(name)
    for j, job in enumerate(jobs, 1):
        jobstr = 'Job {0}'.format(j)
        jobeffdatestr = 'Job Eff Date {0}'.format(j)
        if jobstr not in dic:
            dic[jobstr] = ['']*(len(dic['Name'])-1)
            dic[jobeffdatestr] = ['']*(len(dic['Name'])-1)
        dic[jobstr].append(df['Job'].ix[job])
        dic[jobeffdatestr].append(df['Job Eff Date'].ix[job])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(dic).set_index('Name')

##         Job 1    Job 2     Job 3 Job Eff Date 1 Job Eff Date 2 Job Eff Date 3
## Name                                                                         
## Jane  Analyst  Manager                 1/1/2015       1/1/2016               
## Joe   Analyst  Manager  Director       1/1/2015       1/1/2016       7/1/2016
```

Comment: Thanks Julien. I received the following error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-052b194814e6> in <module>()
      3 dic = {}
      4 
----> 5 for name, jobs in df.groupby('Name').groups.iteritems():
      6     if not dic:
      7         dic['Name'] = []

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: You're welcome :-) you're using Python 3, just delete `.iteritems()`

Answer (score 1):

```
g = df2.groupby('Name').groups
names = list(g.keys())
data2 = {'Name': names}
cols = ['Name']
temp1 = [g[y] for y in names]
job_str = 'Job'
job_date_str = 'Job Eff Date'
for i in range(max([len(x) for x in g.values()])):
    temp = [x[i] if len(x) > i else '' for x in temp1]
    job_str_curr = job_str + str(i+1)
    job_date_curr = job_date_str + str(i + 1)
    data2[job_str + str(i+1)] = df2[job_str].ix[temp].values
    data2[job_date_str + str(i+1)] = df2[job_date_str].ix[temp].values
    cols.extend([job_str_curr, job_date_curr])

df3 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=cols)
df3 = df3.fillna('')
print(df3)
```

> ```
>    Name     Job1 Job Eff Date1     Job2 Job Eff Date2      Job3 Job Eff Date3
> 0  Jane  Analyst      1/1/2015  Manager      1/1/2016                        
> 1   Joe  Analyst      1/1/2015  Manager      1/1/2016  Director      7/1/2016
> ```

Comment: Thanks Ophir. I don't know where to begin on how this works. Are there any resources I could look through to understand more?

Comment: gropby
:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Comment: fillna :
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

Comment: ix: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you were asking but here is a way to print the data frame as you wanted:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
for name, jobs in df.groupby('Name').groups.iteritems():
    print '{0:<15}'.format(name),
    for job in jobs:
        print '{0:<15}{1:<15}'.format(df['Job'].ix[job], df['Job Eff Date'].ix[job]),
    print

## Jane            Analyst        1/1/2015        Manager        1/1/2016       
## Joe             Analyst        1/1/2015        Manager        1/1/2016        Director       7/1/2016
```

Comment: Thanks Julien.

I'm getting an error: File "<ipython-input-3-216784a9e7ca>", line 3
    print '{0:<15}'.format(name),
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I'll need to do some more work in the dataframe, so not sure this solution would work. It is an interesting thought though.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm guessing you are using Python 3. Replace all `print blahblah` by `print(blahblah)`

Answer (score 0):

Diving into @piRSquared answer....

```
def tgrp(df):
    df  = df.drop('Name', axis=1)
    print df, '\n'   
    out =  df.reset_index(drop=True)   
    print out, '\n'
    out.T 
    print out.T, '\n\n'
    return  out.T

dfxx = df2.groupby('Name').apply(tgrp).unstack()
dfxx
```

The output of above. Why does pandas repeat the first group? Is this a bug?

```
       Job Job Eff Date
3  Analyst     1/1/2015
4  Manager     1/1/2016 

       Job Job Eff Date
0  Analyst     1/1/2015
1  Manager     1/1/2016 

                     0         1
Job            Analyst   Manager
Job Eff Date  1/1/2015  1/1/2016 


       Job Job Eff Date
3  Analyst     1/1/2015
4  Manager     1/1/2016 

       Job Job Eff Date
0  Analyst     1/1/2015
1  Manager     1/1/2016 

                     0         1
Job            Analyst   Manager
Job Eff Date  1/1/2015  1/1/2016 


        Job Job Eff Date
0   Analyst     1/1/2015
1   Manager     1/1/2016
2  Director     7/1/2016 

        Job Job Eff Date
0   Analyst     1/1/2015
1   Manager     1/1/2016
2  Director     7/1/2016 

                     0         1         2
Job            Analyst   Manager  Director
Job Eff Date  1/1/2015  1/1/2016  7/1/2016
```